# Log4j and ${HOME} variable - HOME does not expand as expected

Tags: java, linux, log4j

I am still using log4j-1.2.14.jar

In the property I tried to use

```
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${HOME}/logs/App.log
```

When I start up my app I got this exception?

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logs/App.log (No such file or directory)
```

It seems like `${HOME}` is not available when log4j is started.

What is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${HOME}` is a bash variable that has no meaning in a java properties file.

You may want `${user.home}`